# Check if your iPhone has any pending UILocalNotifications

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, push-notification, uilocalnotification

I'm doing some development on my iPhone involving `UILocalNotification`s, and I'm wondering if how to check if any are pending on my phone, and if so, if I'm able to edit or delete them.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean notifications for your app, or for all the apps on the phone?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to look at `UIApplication`. All you're asking for is available in this class. For instance, to list all the scheduled notifications, have a look here : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728-CH3-SW91